# Why this EditText's width strange behaviour when used as ActionBar custom view?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-actionbar

I'm using an `EditText` into the `ActionBar` as custom view.

```
LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View etSearchView = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_search, null);
etSearch = (EditText) etSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

//other etSearch properties are set

MainActivity.ab.setCustomView(etSearch);
```

edit_text_search.xml:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect"
    android:hint="@string/keywords"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white">
</EditText>
```

I have this behaviour... (undesired)

[image: wrong]

On the other hand, when the `EditText`'s width and height are declared in code with

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
etSearch.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and removing `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` from the xml file, I have this (desired) look...

[image: right]

How is this possible, with the same width and height?

Is this because, in code, they imply the addition of a wrapping layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is this possible, with the same width and height?

The layout params used in your `EditText` are different layout params than the ones applied when you add a `View` to the `ActionBar`. Every `ViewGroup` has a nested class that implements their own [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

By default, the [`ActionBar.LayoutParams` are set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ActionBar.java#L1048), so when you don't apply your own through `ActionBar.setCustomView(View, LayoutParams)`, [the `ActionBar` falls back on the default.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L799)

Comment: OMG. Are you *that* Andrew Neal ?! Respect... (and thanks for the answer) I love Apollo. ;)